# Change a For Loop to a Do While statement?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

```
Module Module1 
   Sub Main() 
      For value As Integer = 9 To 0 'Step 1'
         System.Console.WriteLine(value) 
      Next 
   End Sub 
End Module
```

This should be simple id imagine, how could this easily be changed from a "For Loop" to a "Do While" statement?

Comment: You mean `Step -1`. Is it a typo?

Comment: Do whiles will loop until some condition is no longer met.  It's unclear what part of that you are stuck on.

Comment: Sorry! @MatSnow Meant to be a comment. Will edit

Comment: @LarsTech I want to learn how to change this "For Loop" to a "Do while" statement thats what I'm stuck on.

Comment: Now it makes even less sense. It will never enter the loop like this.

Comment: @MatSnow my apologies still learning .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [`Do While`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement) loop instead:

```
Dim value As Integer = 9

Do While value <= 9 And value >= 0
    Console.WriteLine(value)
    value -= 1 'this count from 9 to 0
Loop
```

But your [`For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) doesn't work this way. At the moment you [`For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) loop doesn't output any value. It looks like you set the wrong steps:

```
For value As Integer = 9 To 0 Step -1
    Console.WriteLine(value) 'this count from 9 to 0
Next
```

---

The [`Do While`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement) loop solution to count from 0 to 9:

```
Dim value As Integer = 0

Do While value <= 9 And value >= 0
    Console.WriteLine(value)
    value += 1 'this count from 0 to 9
Loop
```

The [`For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) loop solution to count from 0 to 9:

```
For value As Integer = 0 To 9 Step 1
    Console.WriteLine(value) 'this count from 0 to 9
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This will never enter the loop, as the start value is higher than the end, and the step is not negative. See here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement#technical-implementation
 To turn this into a Do-While, you would have to first check if the start and end conditions are valid, otherwise it would be stuck in an infinite loop.